# How to debug PHP in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I installed Xdebug in Visual Studio Code. But I can't find out a way to debug PHP file line by line. I want to put a break point and debug code step by step.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of vscode-php-debug (1.20.0) VS Code extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) allows you to run and debug the currently open file right away.

You need a PHP installation and the Xdebug PHP Extension.

On Windows:

- download PHP from https://windows.php.net/download/. Install it, or drop it in a folder
- download the right Xdebug .dll from https://xdebug.org/download#releases and put it in your phps ext directory.
- you can even use https://xdebug.org/wizard to help you figure out what to download and where to put it
- edit your php.ini file to add `zend_extension=xdebug...dll`
- Open a php file in your VS Code and press F5.
- If VS Code can't find your php.exe by itself it will point you to settings where you can provide a path to it.

It's similar on Linux, but you will probably want to use your native package manager to install php-cli and php-xdebug, or similar.